# Appending string in the existing code block based on matching string

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have below block of code in tf file.

```
variable "dev_team" {
  default = [
    "dev/global",
    "dev/software",
  ]
}
```

and I want to add a string (after I found a match `dev` in the file) just above the closing square brackets. Input string eg is `dev/hardware`. The output should be like below.

```
variable "dev_team" {
  default = [
    "dev/global",
    "dev/software",
    "dev/hardware",
  ]
}
```

NOTE:  "dev/software", will not always be the last items, it could be any string ("dev/" )but I just want to add new string in the new line before the closing square brackets.

I tried using sed command to match the code block having `dev` string using sed and tried to append the new string but it doesn't work as required and instead add the string before every `dev` match.

```
sed -ie 's/dev/hardware &/' test.tf
```

Comment: It may be possible in `sed`, but for a maintainable, extendable solution add an `awk` tag to your question and readers maybe able to help. You should indicate if  `dev/software` will always be the last item in the existing list, OR if you will need it to precede the closing `]`  of the `default` list. Will there ever be block without a default? etc, etc. Good luck.

Comment: updated the description of question. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: which `dev` are you matching on ... `dev_team`? `dev/<anything>`? something else? what if `dev` shows up elsewhere in the tf file? please update the question with more details on how to determine which part of the file to search for `dev`

Comment: dev can match on both (dev_team and dev/<anything> ) and it also takes the exception that it will not be present elsewhere in the file but only on single variable block.

Comment: `sed` is not the best tool to edit tf files. Use the command `terraform console` and invoke the function `concat(var.dev_team, ["dev/hardware"])` to add an item to the array (in last position). I couldn't test it because I don't have Terraform installed.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v old='"dev/' -v new='"dev/hardware",' '
    s = index($0,old) {
        indent = substr($0,1,s-1)
        f = 1
    }
    f && /]/ {
        print indent new
        f = 0
    }
    { print }
' test.tf
variable "dev_team" {
  default = [
    "dev/global",
    "dev/software",
    "dev/hardware",
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped, but awk -v command is not actually appending the string instead simply printing the output in the terminal. How can I save that output to the file. I am referring to an alternative of -i parameter of sed (but how to use it in awk). awk -iv doesnt seem to be working. :(

Comment: In UNIX only editors (e.g. `ed`, `vi`, `vim`, `emacs`, `nano`, `pico`) edit files, all other text processing tools read input and produce output to stdout unless directed to do otherwise. The GNU awk equivalent of GNU sed's `-i` is `-i inplace` but with any awk (or any other Unix tool) you can alternatively just add `> tmp && mv tmp test.tf` to the end of the command line to overwrite the input file. If you type `man awk` at the command line it'll tell you what options it supports.

Comment: the test.tf file has many other variables defined, adding > tmp && mv tmp test.tf will overrite all the other lines

Comment: @bsgta why not just try it? **Any** Unix tool will overwrite the whole input file but my script will only **change** the lines you asked to have changed, all of the other lines will remain as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU AWK

```
awk -v st="hardware" '
    /dev\//{new=gensub(/([^\/]*\/)([^"]*)(",)/,"\\1"st"\\3",1)} 
    /\]/{print new}1
' file

variable "dev_team" {
  default = [
    "dev/global",
    "dev/software",
    "dev/hardware",
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's probably unlikely given what the OP has shown in their example but IMO it's worth mentioning that using `st` as replacement text in `gensub()` would fail if `st` contained a backreference char/string such is `&` or `\\1`. I'd always use `sub(/foo$/,"",str) str=str new` over `sub(/foo$/,new,str)` for that reason - it's just a few more chars typing but makes `new` be treated literally so you then don't care what chars/substrings it contains. You don't need to escape `]` btw - it's only a metacharacter if it's preceded by a `[` that starts a bracket expression.

Answer (score 0):

it's brute force but gets the job done :

> ```
> mawk 7 RS='[ \t]*[]]\n[}]\n' ORS='    "dev/hardware",\n  ]\n}\n'
> ```

```
variable "dev_team" {
  default = [
    "dev/global",
    "dev/software",
    "dev/hardware",
  ]
}
```

Comment: this is not correct output,
variable "dev_team" {
  default = [
    "dev/global",
    "dev/software",
  ]
}   "dev/hardware",
  ]
}

Comment: @bsgta : how are you running it ? my output matches your desired output